# Setting Orientation in Gluon Application

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I want to prevent my Gluon Application which written with javaFX from rotating by setting the Orientation to Portrait only

anyone can help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml under the activity tag:

```
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```